# LEFT JOIN functionality in a (maybe) double joined query with WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have the following 3 tables:

```
Clients AS c
--------
ClientID,
ClientGUID,
InitializationDate,
LastCheckin

ClientServices AS cs
---------------
ClientID,
ServiceID,
Status,
Version

Services AS s
---------
ServiceID,
Name,
Description
```

I need to build a query that will give me the following results:

```
s.Name, cs.Version
```

I need it to act as a left join, in the sense that I'd like to have all Services display, regardless of whether that service is in ClientServices.  The selected version will simply display as `NULL` in this case.

I tried doing some simple joins, but every combination of `LEFT JOIN` and `JOIN` I used resulted in ONLY the `ClientServices` that belonged to that client showing up.  An example:

```
SELECT    s.`Name`, 
          cs.`Version` 
FROM      `Services` s LEFT JOIN ClientServices cs ON 
          s.`ServiceID` = cs.`ServiceID` 
          JOIN Clients c ON 
          cs.`ClientID` = c.`ClientID` 
WHERE     `ClientGUID`='thisisanewguid'
```

I was able to finally get the desired result with this query:

```
SELECT    s.`Name`, 
          cs.`Version` 
FROM      `Services` s LEFT JOIN ClientServices cs 
          ON s.`ServiceID` = cs.`ServiceID` 
WHERE     cs.ClientID = (
                            SELECT    ClientID 
                            FROM      Clients 
                            WHERE     ClientGUID='thisisanewguid'
                        ) 
OR        cs.ClientID IS NULL
```

but I feel as though its a little "hacky".  Is there a better way to get the same result set, but without doing multiple selects in one query? (preferably with only joins, but I'm not sure if thats possible anymore)

**Example Data Set:**

**Clients:**

```
ClientID,         ClientGUID, InitializationDate, LastCheckin
       1, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',         10/10/2017,  10/12/2017
       2,   'thisisanewguid',         05/23/2017,  10/12/2017
```

**ClientServices:**

```
ClientID, ServiceID, Status, Version
       1,         1,      1,   '0.1'
       2,         1,      1,   '0.1'
       2,         2,      1,   '0.2'
```

**Services:**

```
ServiceID,        Name,                              Description
        1, InITManager, 'Manages and updates all InIT services.'
        2,     InITIAM,     'InIT's Inventory/Asset Management.'
        3, InITTesting,                                'testing'
```

**Desired Result Set WHERE ClientGUID='thisisanewguid':**

```
       Name, Version
InITManager,   '0.1'
    InITIAM,   '0.2'
InITTesting,    NULL
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: A left join produces a null when no result is found and an inner join drops the row if no record is found.  You start at table s left join to cs..so cs null is valid and you will see results from s that have no corresponding cs entry at this point.  You then inner join to c from cs...all nulls that were left behind from the first left join are now filtered out at this join.  Make sense?  left join followed by an inner join is self defeating.

Comment: That does make sense, and I did think of that after it didn't work, but when I then proceeded to try two `LEFT JOIN`'s, It still doesn't work because I have to specify `WHERE c.ClientGUID = 'thisisanewguid'`.  In fact, the more I think about it, the more I tend to conclude that my second query is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for obatin the result you showed  in question you could use left   table  with left join  without where clause for column involved  id left join

```
SELECT    s.`Name`, 
          cs.`Version` 
FROM      `Services` s 
LEFT JOIN ClientServices cs ON   s.`ServiceID` = cs.`ServiceID` 
LEFT JOIN Clients c ON c.ClientID = cs.ClientID  AND c.`ClientGUID`='thisisanewguid'
```

Comment: With this, I'd have no way to specify `WHERE ClientGUID = 'thisisanewguid'`

Comment: Thanks!  I never actually thought of or knew you could use 'AND' in a JOIN.  Thanks again.

Comment: You need  the and condition in this case  becase  if you use where then you have not a left join but a inner  join

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari   .. thanks  ..  lloking to your code  .. suggest you the use of left  join  (instead  of right )  is the natural set thery approach for this case

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please try the following query

```
SELECT cs.Version, s.Name 
FROM ClientServices cs
RIGHT JOIN Clients c ON c.ClientID = cs.ClientID
RIGHT JOIN Services s ON s.ServiceID = cs.ServiceID
```

Comment: That almost has the functionality I'm looking for...  But if I add `WHERE c.ClientGUID = 'thisisanewguid'`, then I get only InITManager and InITIAM.